# Preload progressDialog makes my app crash only in ICS

Tags: android, crash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, preload

So I'm using this code to show the message "Installing..." while the database is setup with the function 'setUpDB' and is then removed when the database function has completed. This works fine in Gingerbread and honeycomb, but causes the application to crash in ICS

```
        final ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Installing...");

    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            if(msg.what==0)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };   


    //have subcategory heading???
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        setUpDB();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```

Without dismissing the message, the app will continue to run in ICS (but you can't do anything), and without displaying the message if the user does anything that accesses the database before it is finished being setup it will crash (thus why I need the installing message)..

Okay, here is the code using AsyncTask

```
    final ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Installing...");
    final Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            if(msg.what==0)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };   
    new databaseInstallTask().execute(handler);
```

And

```
    private class databaseInstallTask extends AsyncTask<Handler, Void, Handler> 
{       
        @Override
        protected Handler doInBackground(Handler... params) {
            setUpDB();
            return params[0];
        }

    protected void onPostExecute(Handler handler) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is perfectly fine!! it should work!!show us your crash logs

Comment: It works fine on anything before ICS. Perhaps Handler is breaking the second rule of Android threading?

1) Do not block the UI thread
2) Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try using `Asynctask` which I suppose is the most appropriate way to handle your case.

Comment: Okay I've got an AsyncTask working on it's own, but will check it with the rest of the code tonight (see above). Is there a better way to get the Handler to onPostExecute without going through doInbackground?